# Forbidden column name in Azure table storage

Tags: .net, database-design, azure, model

Why am I getting errors when working with a new table that has only one **user defined** column:

- "an error occurred while processing this request"
- "Only collections of entities are supported"

Comment: Can you post the code of the class definition for your entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many reasons of course, but in any case - **don't name your column "Properties"**.

Edit: One column besides the predefined ones - `PartitionKey`, `RowKey`, and `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be Azure Table with just one column! The minimum is 3 - `PartitionKey`, `RowKey`, `Timestamp`.

Please read through [Understanding Table Service Data model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx), before asking questions. And then come with specific question backed up by facts, code snippets, full stack traces, etc.